# Shipping tag on suitcase vs. on handle

Tags: luggage, damaged-luggage

The shipping company in Japan broke my luggage handle so when I checked my bags, there was no place to put the tag that says which airport it needs to go to.  They put the sticker on side of my suitcase instead.  How well will this hold up???  I am so nervous about losing my luggage, it has my souvenirs in it

Answer (score 4):

If your referring to the baggage handling tag that the airline puts on at the airport, the whole tag is a sticky label that can be applied to flat objects like boxes or handle-less suitcases.

The agent should also peel off a smaller “backup tag” and stick it on another area of the luggage. This is in case the main label gets torn off. So make sure you don’t have any old backup tags on your luggage and make sure the agent sticks one on (they often forget).

If you’re really worried, bring some clear packing tape and tape down the edges of your main tag when you check in. But that may be overkill.

Note: some plastic suitcases have a bumpy texture that makes it hard for stickers and tape to stick. In those cases you may indeed want to figure out how to provide a better surface for the luggage tag to stick if there’s nowhere for it to go.

Finally, most checkin agents have used the suitcase pull handle when the carry handle is sketchy.

Also, Japanese delivery companies are really good in terms of compensation. I’d honestly just get a new suitcase and bill them.

Comment: Thank you!  I discovered the handle was broken when I got to the airport, the delivery company delivered it to the airport for me so I did not have time to buy a new suitcase and did not have any things to stick it down with.  I honestly didn't even think about it until I went to check it and they put the handling tag on the suitcase itself.  It wasn't until then that I started wondering how well that will stick to the suitcase.  Thank you so much for your reply.  It does make me feel better.  I figured the person putting on my luggage has probably dealt with this once or twice.  Thank you!